# Using ASP.NET MVC 5, how do I get the localized DisplayAttribute string for an Enum value in a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, enums, localization

If I am using the `DisplayAttribute` on an `Enum` value, how do I get the localized resource value based on the `Enum` value.

For example, if I have an `Enum` defined as the following:

```
public enum ExpireMode {
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (ModelRes.ExpireMode), Name = "Never")]
    Never = 0,

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (ModelRes.ExpireMode), Name = "ByCreated")]
    ByCreated = 1,

    [Display(ResourceType = typeof (ModelRes.ExpireMode), Name = "ByLastAccessed")]
    ByLastAccessed = 2,
}
```

And, we assume I have created a `.resx` file with the custom namespace of ModelRes that contains the following:

[image]

How, would I retrieve the proper localized value if all I have is the value of the enum?  I would like to use the proper localized value for display in a View.

I have looked at solutions that use type converters, extension methods, etc., but all seem to add a lot of code that should be relatively straightforward.  Using the `DisplayAttribute` for all other purposes makes localization pretty trivial as it handles it internally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I found to solve this problem that does not require any extra code is the following code in the View itself:

```
@ModelRes.ExpireMode.ResourceManager.GetString(Model.ExpireMode.ToString())
```

`Model.ExpireMode` is a property on the model of the `Enum` type `ExpireMode`.  `ModelRes` is the custom namespace for the resource class `ExpireMode`.  I grab the `ResourceManager` and call `GetString` with the string representation of the enum value, which gives me the properly localized value.